# Moore-Penrose Inverse of sum of two matrices using spectral decomposition

Tags: matrices, matrix-decomposition, pseudoinverse

Suppose $X$ is $n \times n$ symmetric with $rank(X)=p$.

If Y is $n \times n$ matrix with $rank(Y) = n-p$, such that $XY=(0)$ then it follows that $X^{+}X + Y^{+}Y = I_{n}$

How to show this? I believe we need to use spectral decomposition of X to show the result.

Comment: Hint: svd and it's pretty straight forward. Your $m$ is a $n$, right?

Comment: Yes, I'll make an edit. Singular value decomposition is the trick?

Comment: for me at least. You should think about the null space of $X$ and the image of $Y$.

Comment: I'm not following. Any further clarification?

Comment: Well, $X^+X$ and $Y^+Y$ are diagonal with 0 and 1 on there diagonal. To obtain their order you need that $XY=0$ part and to obtain their numbers you need the rank part. Btw, I missed that the matrices are symmetric. Thus, you can also use the eigenvalue decomposition.